# Regarding empty initialisation of static array of class types

Tags: c++, arrays, static, initialization

When I ran static code analyzer QACPP, I got a warning. According to the QACPP documentation, initializing with `{0}` only works for built in types. To initialize an array of objects of type `A`, `{}` must be used. As below:

```
int i[5] = {0};  // Only works with built-in types.
A   a[5] = {};   // OK, works with both built-in and class types
```

Is this a standard C++ rule? According to this, an array of pointers to a class type must also be initialized with `{}`, right?

Does this statement:

```
A* ap[5] = {}
```

initialise the 5 pointers with `NULL`?

QACPP throws me a warning when I used `A* ap[5] = {NULL}`, though the code compiles and works perfectly even otherwise.

---

#### Additional

I think the warning was more because the array is static.

And here is the explanation I found in the documentation:

> There are many problems with the use
>   of objects with static storage
>   duration, particularly those declared
>   outside of functions. If many
>   functions can access a static object
>   this situation may become difficult to
>   maintain. Also, in the case of
>   multi-threaded applications it becomes
>   necessary to protect with mutex each
>   static object that can be accessed
>   concurrently. It is therefore a good
>   idea to limit the scope of a static
>   object as much as possible, so that
>   you know where such object is
>   accessed.
>
> Namespace or class objects with static
>   storage duration will be initialised
>   at the start of the program, before
>   calling main(), and the order of
>   initialisation is unspecified.
>   Reliance on the order of
>   initialisation may lead to objects
>   being used before they are
>   initialised. If an exception is thrown
>   as a result of initialising a
>   non-local object the program will
>   immediately terminate.
>
> Block scope objects with static
>   storage duration will be initialised
>   when the function is first called.
>   Therefore, it is best to use the
>   singleton pattern instead of namespace
>   objects and static data members. This
>   entails wrapping the object in a
>   function as a local static object, and
>   having the function return a reference
>   to this object.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special

Comment: `A*` is a built-in type. `0` should work for that, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a standard rule. An array is an aggregate. The rules of initialization are explicitly mentioned in the standard for aggregates.

> Does this statement: A* ap[5] = {}
>   intialise the 5 pointers with NULL?

**Yes**

> QACPP throws me a warning when I used A* ap[5] = {NULL}

What warning? Maybe the warning is that you initialized only the first element, and the others will stay NULL. Of course, it may be what you need. But then, the compiler is just warning you :)

I think this question and answer will be very interesting. [What are Aggregates and PODs and how/why are they special?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special)

Comment: Thanks Armen. I intend to give that link a full read soon, but I needed to know one more thing asap. If the array of pointers I describe is a static array, will it still be initialised on this statement? On using {NULL}, QACPP warning says "This non-local aggregate will be intialised at run-time". The proposed solution goes on to say "Use singleton class instance in turn". However, the warning disappears if I initialise the array with empty braces {} in stead of with {NULL}. Hence, the confusion whether it really does get intialised(since it is static, this is crucial).

Comment: @kiki: You can rest assured that all will be initialized with NULL. I don't know what singleton has to do with initialization of aggregates... Oh, wait, I know - nothing :)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, pointers it is built-in types too, so statement `A* ap[5] = {NULL}` is fine.