# Regarding 2-d array initialisation in C++

Tags: c++, initialization, aggregate, multidimensional-array

I get mixed responses for this question on 2-d array initialization in C++.

Here's the scenario:

```
class MyClass {
   private:
      static char my2dArray[10][20];
}; 

char MyClass::my2dArray[10][20] = {{0}};
```

Now does this initialize all elements of this array with 0?

Also, if I have the following type definition:

```
typedef unsigned char u8;
```

and this array is `static u8 my2dArray[10][20]`, will the same initialization work?

Assuming it's mandatory that all elements are explicitly initialized to 0.

Comment: What do you mean, you get mixed responses? Have you already asked it, or something?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545012/regarding-empty-initialisation-of-static-array-of-class-types

Comment: Yea i asked before in stack overflow as well as to colleagues in person. That's when I got mixed responses.

Comment: I hope my answer satisfies you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> class MyClass {
>    private:
>      static char my2dArray[10][20];
> }; 
>
> char MyClass::my2dArray[10][20] = {{0}};
> ```
>
> Now does this initialize all elements of this array with 0?

Sort of.

Recall that the elements of your array are not `char`, but `char[10]` (which cannot be `0`).

What you're doing here is initialising the outer array by providing an initialiser for the *first* inner array (`{0}`, again setting only the inner array's *first* element to `0`).

You're then letting the "default", implicit initialization behaviour take over for the subsequent elements in both arrays.

> `[n3290: 8.5.1/1]:` **An *aggregate* is an array** or a class (Clause 9)
>   with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no
>   *brace-or-equal-initializers* for non-static data members (9.2), no
>   private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), no base
>   classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions.
>
> `[n3290: 8.5.1/2]:` When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer
>   list, as specified in 8.5.4, **the elements of the initializer list are
>   taken as initializers for the members of the aggregate, in increasing
>   subscript or member order**. Each member is copy-initialized from the
>   corresponding *initializer-clause*. If the *initializer-clause* is an
>   expression and a narrowing conversion (8.5.4) is required to convert
>   the expression, the program is ill-formed. [ *Note*: **If an
>   *initializer-clause* is itself an initializer list, the member is
>   list-initialized, which will result in a recursive application of the
>   rules in this section if the member is an aggregate.** *—end note* ]
>
> `[n3290: 8.5.1/7:]` If there are fewer *initializer-clauses* in the list
>   than there are members in the aggregate, then **each member not
>   explicitly initialized shall be initialized from an empty initializer
>   list** (8.5.4).
>
> `[n3290: 8.5.4/3:]` [..] Otherwise, **if the initializer list has no
>   elements, the object is value-initialized.** [..]

The [final draft] standard actually contains a non-normative example of a similar behaviour:

> `[n3290: 8.5.1/10]:` [..] [ *Example:* [..] On the other hand,
>
> ```
> float y[4][3] = { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 }, { 4 } };
> ```
>
> initializes the first column of `y` (regarded as a two-dimensional
>   array) **and leaves the rest zero.** *—end example* ]

So, ultimately, yes. All of your innermost array elements will hold the value `0`; it's just that your `{{0}}` didn't actually do very much to make that happen.

---

> Assuming it's mandatory that all elements are explicitly initialized to 0.

Well, since your array has `static` storage duration, its memory will be zero-initialised anyway, so this is ultimately pointless to bother concerning yourself over.

---

> Also, if I have the following type definition:
>
> ```
> typedef unsigned char u8;
> ```
>
> and this array is `static u8 my2dArray[10][20]`, will the same initialization work?

Yes. The type alias doesn't change anything: this array has precisely the same type (and storage duration) as the first one, and the same rules apply.

Answer (score 3):

> Now does this initialize all elements of this array with 0?

Yes
If the initializer list does not have the same number of elements as the actual array. Then the array is zero filled.

> will the same initialization work?

Yes
The same processes is at work here.

Comment: Is this similar to how char a[10] = {0} fills all elements of the 1-d array with 0? This is my first attempt with 2-d array. Also, if this was array of class pointers, i should initialise with {} for 1-d and {{}} for 2-d?

Comment: @kiki: You should be aware that there is nothing magical about your `0` there; `char a[10] = {1}` initialises the first element to `1`, and all the rest are value-initialised ... i.e. they are initialised to `0`. i.e. the value you give there is _not_ a value that will propagate through all the array's elements. Thus, your `char a[10] = {0}` might as well be `char a[10] = {}`.